# iOS app(swift) - How to handle offline notifications

Tags: ios

I am using the pubnub idk to deliver push notifications to my app.

I enabled the remote notifications in the Background mode setting which is in the capabilities tab in Xcode

1) App in background state(online):
I am using didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler: I can able to get the notification info. But I can't hit any web service at this instance. If it possible to hit web service, May I know how much time it will process.

2) App in background state(offline):
When switching from offline to online, it always delivers the latest push notification of all which supposed to be delivered in offline. May I know How to stop receiving the latest push notification.

Thanks